# CFAttributedString thread safety

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-foundation

Is this code showing that CFAttributedString isn't thread safe? Or am I doing something wrong in the setup?

I thought that CFAttributedString was safe to read from multiple threads, but I see crashes in this code every few runs.

```
@IBAction func testIt(_ sender: Any?) {
    let testString = "Hello world! Lets make this a bit longerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr." as CFString
    let testStringLength = CFStringGetLength(testString)

    let testAttributedString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, testStringLength)
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString(testAttributedString, CFRange(location: 0, length: 0), testString)
    CFAttributedStringEndEditing(testAttributedString)
    for i in 0..<testStringLength {
        let range = CFRange(location: i, length: 1)
        let keyAndValue = "\(i)" as CFString
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(testAttributedString, range, keyAndValue, keyAndValue)
    }

    let immutableTestAttributedString = CFAttributedStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, testAttributedString)
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100) { _ in
        var index: CFIndex = 0
        var effectiveRange: CFRange = CFRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        while index < testStringLength {
            // Crash happens here EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x24)
            let _ = CFAttributedStringGetAttributes(immutableTestAttributedString, index, &effectiveRange)
            index = effectiveRange.location + effectiveRange.length
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let testString = "Hello world! Lets make this a bit longerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr." as CFString
```

This is a Swift string masquerading as a `CFString`, which is about two layers of indirection and invokes a very different code path down in the guts (whether that should still work or not is between you and a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com)).

Try creating a proper `CFString` and see if it works the way you expect.

```
var bytes = Array("Hello world! Lets make this a bit longerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.".utf16)
let testString = CFStringCreateWithCharacters(nil, &bytes, bytes.count)
```

(Of course I highly recommend doing all this work in `NSAttributedString` rather than `CFAttributedString`. The Swift->Foundation bridging is much simpler and is used constantly compared to the Swift->Foundation->CoreFoundation bridging. This may just be a bug in that bridging, but your world is still going to be a lot easier if you avoid it.)

---

While I haven't been able to reproduce the problem w/ a pure CFString, this is definitely not thread safe. CoreFoundation is open source (sort-of…, but enough for this purpose), so you can look at the code yourself. Eventually `CFAttributedStringGetAttributes` calls [`blockForLocation`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/String.subproj/CFRunArray.c#L60-L80), which updates an internal cache and does not having locking around that. I haven't seen anything in the docs that promises this is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately I'm still seeing an error in the same place when I create the string that way. The reason for using CFAttributedString in this case is because it's a hot place in the code and CFAttributedStringSetAttribute seems to run a lot faster then adding attributes with NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Do you have any pointers to where I can learn more about how swift bridging works? And especially performance issues to watch for. I'm doing a lot of work with Core Text from Swift and am now in optimization phase. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I was expecting thread safe since NSAttributedString is listed as safe and Core Foundation was advertised as "generally" safe here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html But in this case NOT, very good to know and thanks again for your help.

Comment: I be tempted to open a radar here, at the very least for the docs. I keep thinking about this, and lines like "[Core Foundation] is thread-safe in the common cases, such as when you query, retain, release, and pass around immutable objects" is incredibly misleading if that doesn't include `CFAttributedStringGetAttributes`. How is that not a a "common case…when you query…immutable objects."